# I was wondring how to get data from WCF server using soap obejct

Tags: android, web-services, wcf, soap

I hope anybody solve my problem. I'm almost using 3 days to solve this problem...

Firstly this is URL :  http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL

Below is my full code

```
package com.webservice;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;



 public   class MainActivity   extends Activity 

{

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private   static final String   SOAP_ACTION1 =   "http://www.w3schools.com/webServices/FahrenheitToCelsius";

    private   static final String   SOAP_ACTION2 =   "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit";

    private   static final String   NAMESPACE =   "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";

    private   static final String   METHOD_NAME1 =  "FahrenheitToCelsius";

    private   static final String   METHOD_NAME2 =  "CelsiusToFahrenheit";

    private   static final String  URL =   "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";



   private Button   btnFar,btnCel,btnClear;

  private EditText   txtFar,txtCel;

  private String response;



  @Override

  public   void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



      btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFar);

      btnCel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCel);

      btnClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

      txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFar);

    txtCel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCel);

    btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
            myAsyncTask myRequest = new myAsyncTask();
            myRequest.execute();                
        }
    });

}

  private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
  {
      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
          super.onPostExecute(result);
          txtFar.setText(response);
          txtCel.setText(response);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();       
      }

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
      {
          SoapObject request =  new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,   METHOD_NAME1);        
        request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtFar.getText().toString());

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =  new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet =   true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport =  new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

            SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();          

             if(result !=   null)
             {
                 Log.d("App",""+result.getAttribute(2).toString());
                 response=result.getAttribute(1).toString();     
             }
             else{}


      }   catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

      }
       return null;        
      }   
  }
```

}

When I debug this code, I think there was no problem connecting android with http because

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope); <--- I can pass this line.
```

However after this code, error was caused.

```
SoapPrimitive result=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

> SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction:
>   http://www.w3schools.com/webServices/FahrenheitToCelsius.' faultactor:
>   'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@42a91d88

I tried other code like this.

```
SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn();
```

I guess data type is related with this problem.

So please check my code and URL that I wrote previously

Comment: I solved this problem.
I changed ksoap2 version 2.6 to 3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is very nice example in details which can help you

[link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/)

I hope this will help you .

Comment: Thank you but I refered that site in my early stage.

Comment: Oh I don't have access to that code at the moment. But It is suppose to work with new version also